# Aggregate intraday data

Tags: mysql

As from my previous question, I have this query to perform data aggregation from intraday to daily data

```
SELECT symbol, date, MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
 (select open from A2A a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time limit 1) as open,
 (select close from A2A a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time desc limit 1) as close
FROM A2A a1
WHERE date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 100 day)
GROUP BY symbol, date
ORDER BY symbol, date;
```

but this return less then 100 daily aggregated rows since it use calendar days.

1) How to modify this query to get 100 latest records?

2) How to aggregate to 5 minute data instead of daily (i.e., first row aggregates data from 0900 up to 0904, then from 0905 up to 0909, etc.)?

I use mySQL 5.6.11, data stored are as follow

[image]

I store stock market data 1 minute per row, I have 511 1 minute rows for every day (from 0900 up to 1730).

Comment: First of, your `order by` is useless, next - what do you mean _"since it use calendar days"_ - yes, it does. But what do you want to achieve? If there's no data for some day - there will be no results then

Comment: @AlmaDo...yes correct, data are stored only from monday to friday, so any saturday and sundays (plus holydays) are not available in my table.This query return 64 days about, so I get 64 rows, how to return 100 rows instead of 64?

Comment: This is a very common problem. It's about filling gaps - and since in MySQL there are no sequences, most common and simple solution is to create second table, then fill it with consecutive dates and then use it for `JOIN`

Comment: You can use a sub query that generates a list of days, and left join your current query against that

Comment: @Kickstart...can you please post an example?

Comment: To aggregate 5 min data you can use convert time to int and divide it by 5 and group by that column. Ex `SELECT floor(cast(time as SIGNED)/5) as timeInterval ..... FROM ...... GROUP BY symbol, date, timeInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Rough and untested example.

```
SELECT symbol, Sub1.aDay, MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) as low, SUM(volume) as volume,
 (select open from A2A a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time limit 1) as open,
 (select close from A2A a2 where a1.symbol = a2.symbol and a1.date = a2.date order by time desc limit 1) as close
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (Tens.a * 10 + Units.a) DAY) AS aDay
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units,
    (SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens
) Sub1
LEFT JOIN A2A a1
ON Sub1.aDay = a1.date
GROUP BY symbol, Sub1.aDay
ORDER BY symbol, Sub1.aDay;
```

This is doing a sub query that generates the numbers 0 to 99 and subtracts that as a number of days from the current date. Gives you the 100 day range. Then joins your main table against that list based on the date.